# mail() function bug sometimes (depends on the message)

Tags: php, function, email, send

I've got a strange problem using the mail function.

I had a script working for a while and needed to edit the message of the mail.
It looks like the content of the message causes a bug, and my mail is not sending.

**What i have tried so far:**

I tried with shorter sentences, sometimes it works, sometimes it wont, I don't know why, there are no special characters in my content.

**PHP CODE:**

```
//-----------------------------------------------
//FRONTIERE
//-----------------------------------------------

$frontiere = '-----=' . md5(uniqid(mt_rand()));

//-----------------------------------------------
//HEADERS
//-----------------------------------------------

$headers = 'From: "Exp" <'.$email_expediteur.'>'."\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: <'.$email_reply.'>'."\n";
$headers .= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset= iso-8859-1\n";

//-----------------------------------------------
//MESSAGE
//-----------------------------------------------
$message = "<img src='http://www.example.com/images/image.gif' /><br />";
$message .="<br />";
$message .= "Dear Sir / Madam,<br /><br />";
$message .= "my email content<br />";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "Best regards,<br />";
$message .= "<br />";

$destinataire = "exemple@example.com";
$sujet = "Brochures";
mail($destinataire,$sujet,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Please post the sentence which is causing the problem.

Comment: Is it happening for any mail id's or just specific ?

Comment: That looks like an html email. That is evil. Don't do that. There is no reason for that.

Comment: @arkascha I would like to agree, but how can I send a mail with pictures and links without doing that?

Comment: @dreamweiver : the user enter its email, and no one can receive anything.

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty : When I remove this sentence it seems to work : "Thank you for your interest in our Advanced Masters and Masters of Science programmes." But as I said, there is nothing specific in that part, so I think the problem is somewhere else. I tried with a completely new message, and what causes the error is really random.

Comment: Most reasonable email client show pictures attached to a message and render embedded urls as clickable links. That should be enough for 99,9% of all situations. If you really (_really_) do need some specific layout in your message then still send a normal, plain text message and include a link to an online version.

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0rn";


$message = "<img src='http://www.example.com/images/image.gif' alt='test' /><br />";
$message .="<br />";
$message .= "Dear Sir / Madam,<br /><br />";
$message .= "my email content<br />";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "Best regards,<br />";
$message .= "<br />";

$destinataire = "exemple@example.com";
$sujet ="Brochures";
mail($destinataire,$sujet,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's not working better unfortunately.By the way I also tried changing $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0rn"; to $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n"; but still the same problem.